# Elasticsearch. Painless script to search based on the last result

Tags: elasticsearch, search, kibana, elasticsearch-painless

Let's see if someone could shed a light on this one, which seems to be a little hard.

We need to correlate data from multiple index and various fields. We are trying painless script.
Example:

- We make a search in an index to gather data about the queueid of mails sent by someone@domain
- Once we have the queueids, we need to store the queueids in an array an iterate over it to make new searchs to gather data like email receivers, spam checks, postfix results and so on.

Problem: Hos can we store the data from one search and use it later in the second search?

We are testing something like:

```
GET here_an_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
             "must": [
            {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-15m",
              "lte": "now"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
            "filter" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "source" : "doc['postfix_from'].value == params.from; qu = doc['postfix_queueid'].value; return qu",
                        "params" : {
                            "from" : "someona@mdomain"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And, of course, it throws an error.

```
"doc['postfix_from'].value ...",
"^---- HERE"
```

So, in a nuttshell: is there any way ti execute a search looking for some field value based on a filter (like from:someone@dfomain) and use this values on later searchs?

We have evaluated using script fields or nested, but due to some architecture reasons and what those changes would  entail, right now, can not be used.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you share your mapping. That would be helpful.

Comment: Also, *How can we store the data from one search and use it later in the second search?* --- Is not possible. This has to be managed in your application layer.